# gtk label text center and wrap

Tags: c, label, gtk2

I have been experiencing some really weird problems with gtk_label text positioning.

I have a gtk_label positioned on a fixed container, the label has been set to:

```
gtk_label_set_justify(GTK_LABEL(label), GTK_JUSTIFY_CENTER);
gtk_label_set_line_wrap(GTK_LABEL(label), TRUE);
```

However when a single word is present in the label, instead of getting centered it gets left aligned.

If I unset `gtk_label_set_line_wrap(GTK_LABEL(label), TRUE)` to `FALSE` the word then appears in the center of the label, but I lose wrapping.

How should this be fixed?

Answer (score 4):

From the [documentation](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk2/stable/GtkLabel.html#gtk-label-set-justify) (emphasis mine):

> #### gtk_label_set_justify ()
>
> Sets the alignment of the lines in the text of the label relative to each other. [`GTK_JUSTIFY_LEFT`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk2/stable/gtk2-Standard-Enumerations.html#GTK-JUSTIFY-LEFT:CAPS) is the default value when the widget is first created with [`gtk_label_new()`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk2/stable/GtkLabel.html#gtk-label-new). If you instead want to set the alignment of the label as a whole, use [`gtk_misc_set_alignment()`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk2/stable/GtkMisc.html#gtk-misc-set-alignment) instead. **[`gtk_label_set_justify()`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk2/stable/GtkLabel.html#gtk-label-set-justify) has no effect on labels containing only a single line.**

As suggested in the above quote, you may wish to add a call to the `gtk_misc_set_alignment()` function, with its `xalign` parameter set to `0.5`, before calling `gtk_label_set_justify()`.